# UPDATE RLS in Supabase seems broken

Tags: supabase, supabase-database

I am trying to set up RLS to a table in Supabase that will only allow the authenticated user to `UPDATE` their row on `users` table. I have opted to use Supabase on my server rather than the front-end. My current workflow is as follows:

1. Client requests a OTP via email
2. User is emailed an OTP
3. OTP is entered into the Client
4. OTP is verified on the server
5. If verified `UPDATE` the users row in the users table with new session details
6. Return the current user details to the Client

Here is the code that is failing:

```js
const { error } = await supabase
  .from('users')
  .update({
    access_token: session.access_token,
    refresh_token: session.refresh_token,
    expires_at: session?.expires_at || 0
  })
  .eq('user_id', user.id)
  .single();
```

Here is the table structure:
[image]

When I run `const user = supabase.auth.user();` I am showing the correct user that has a `user.id` that matches the rows `user_id` column of the row I want to `UPDATE`.

Without RLS set up this workflow is working perfectly. Anything I try fails. Below are the three RLS that I have tried that should work.

1. Checking if user exists `WHERE auth.uid() = users.user_id` in both `USING` and `CHECK`
   [image]
2. Added `auth.uid() = user_id` in both `USING` and `CHECK`
   [image]
3. The weirdest one of the all, set `true` in both `USING` and `CHECK`
   [image]

Here are screen shots of the `uuid` on the `auth.users` table and `user_id` on the `users` table:
[image]
[image]

Attempted this from one of the answers and it is still failing:
[image]

Here is the error response I am receiving from Supabase:
[image]

Comment: To make this easier to debug please setup these policies individually, so setup the INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE policies separately and not try to use one to rule them all. I think the issue is on the SELECTing of the results from the UPDATE. So create a policy for SELECT which just returns true and one for UPDATE with `uid() = user_id` and see what happens.

Comment: I agree with your statement in part Andrew but there is an issue with `UPDATE` statement in Supabase that when utilized actually uses the `SELECT` statement as well meaning if you do not have both set up it will error out unless you add a `{ returning: 'minimal' }` to the `UPDATE` request. Just trying to get this working then I will will dial it in for specific statements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not very well documented yet, but signed in users have `authenticated` role, and not `anon` role, so changing the target role to authenticated should fix it. When in doubt, just leave the target roles blank, which will apply the RLS on all roles.

[image: Set RLS on authenticated]

Comment: Swapped out `anon` with `authenticated` but still receiving the same error. I have added more information to the question to show the id's do match and a picture of trying your solution.

Comment: @CraigHowell Could you share the error message that you are getting?

Comment: @CraigHowell Also, have you tried not specifying any target roles at all?

Comment: I have added the error response to the question. I just removed tried leaving the target role blank and it is now working. Does this mean this is applied to all roles, even the service role?

Comment: @CraigHowell glad to hear that it is working now. Service role will always bypass row level security, so no worried there!

Comment: new row violates row-level security policy for table "user_details

Comment: @JenuelGanawed If you could describe the issue you are having in complete sentences, we might be able to help you.

Comment: I have a user_role table, I would like to use it for managing other tables. But when I try to use it in the policy its having error current I am using something like `EXIST ( SELECT id FROM user_roles WHERE auth.uid() == user_roles.user_id && user_roles.role == 'admin' )` but its throwing an error something like loop errors etc. I dont know why.

Comment: @JenuelGanawed The cause might be the RLS policy you have on the `user_roles` table. What I would suggest is to create a security definer function named something like `is_admin`, have it return a boolean, and put the exist statement in the function. https://supabase.com/docs/guides/database/postgres/row-level-security#use-security-definer-functions