# RLS with Security Definer function returns error with no message, and no error in logs in Supabase / Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, supabase

I have a table called user_roles with three columns: id, user_id, role.
[image]

With RLS disabled, I am able to update rows in this table with the call:

```
 const { data, error } = await supabase
    .from('user_roles')
    .update({ role: role })
    .eq('user_id', id);
```

Now I would like to add RLS so only admins can update the roles of users.
I am aware that this needs to be done in a security definer thanks to these two posts:

[Role based authentication in Supabase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72666758/role-based-authentication-in-supabase)

https://github.com/supabase/supabase/discussions/3328

So I have created an is_admin() security definer function as follows:

```
SELECT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM user_roles
  WHERE user_roles.user_id = _user_id
  AND user_roles.role = 'admin'
);
$$ LANGUAGE sql SECURITY DEFINER;
```

and then I have a policy for updates with USING expression `is_admin(uid())`
[image]
[image]

However when I enable RLS and make my call I get the response:

`error { message: '' }`

There are no errors in my logs so I am unsure how to proceed.

Does anyone have any ideas of what could be wrong or what to investigate next? Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem was because Update also does a Select in supabase so you need a policy for select too or specify `{ returning: "minimal"}` in the update call

https://github.com/supabase/supabase/discussions/5097

in my case I set the Select policy to `(uid() = user_id) OR is_admin(uid())`